# extjs how to bind a field to another existing form

Tags: forms, extjs, filefield

i have a form A containing some fields about questions(a model in my application),but it can not submit directly by form.getForm().submit().the buttons in form A will open another window,and a field on that window.i want to attach the field to form A ,so i can submit those fields together.
the detail is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98YNj.png)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would try to give two different ID's to forms. Next, retrieve the values from them and merge If the field names are different.

```
var first_form_values = Ext.getCmp('first-form').getForm().getValues();
var second_form_values = Ext.getCmp('second-form').getForm().getValues();
var all_values = Ext.Object.merge(first_form_values , second_form_values);
```

Then you have all the values and you can send them by Ext.Ajax etc.

Full example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'First Form',
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {  
            xtype: 'form',
            id: 'first-form',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'First field',
                    name: 'first-field',
                }
            ]
        },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Show second form'
                handler: function()
                {
                    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                        title: 'Second Form',
                        height: 200,
                        width: 400,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        items: {  
                            xtype: 'form',
                            id: 'second-form',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Second field',
                                    name: 'second-field',
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                text: 'Submit'
                                handler: function()
                                {
                                    var first_form = Ext.getCmp('first-form'),
                                        second_form = Ext.getCmp('second-form');
                                    if(first_form && second_form)
                                    {
                                        var fist_form_values = first_form.getForm().getValues(),
                                            second_form_values = second_form.getForm().getValues();

                                        var values = Ext.Object.merge(fist_form_values, second_form_values);  

                                        // You have all values from two forms
                                    }


                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }).show();
                }
            }
        ]
    }).show();
```

Comment: I've tried all what you are doing.it works perfectly.however,my first form contains a filefield,and i simply get the values of the form without the filefield.it's the point that i'm confusing,thank